# Does anyone know how to create COM files with TASM?

Tags: tasm

Does anyone know how to create COM files with TASM? I looked on the internet but I only find webpages that produce OBJ files then use TLINK to produce EXE files. Please Advise.

Answer (score 4):

Use the directives `.MODEL tiny` and `ORG 0100h` in TASM. Use the command line switch `/t` in TLINK:

```
; Name:             hello.asm
; Assemble:         tasm.exe hello.asm
; Link:             tlink.exe /t hello.obj
; Run in DOSBox:    hello.com

.MODEL tiny
.CODE
.386                        ; Just to show at what position it has to be
ORG 0100h

start:

    mov ah, 09h             ; http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm
    mov dx, OFFSET hello
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h           ; http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2974.htm
    int 21h

hello:  db "Hello World", '$'

END start
```